# CSS wont load/be found when having a $_GET in the address

Tags: php, html, css

If I have URL `price.php` and I open the CSS it work's fine. But if I have a `$_GET` in the address, it wont load the CSS, i.e `price.php/?var=DESC`.

Comment: what more infomation do you want?

Comment: Show us `link` tag that you use

Comment: <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 3):

It's because you have a slash `/` before query string. It makes new folder and styles should be linked with `../` at the beginning.

The second, and better way, is to remove slash and have URL like:

```
price.php?var=DESC
```

Comment: Thank you, I have had so much issues with this. I am new to php, so thanks so much